# How to dynamically change the icon on a button based value in a list?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have the following xaml code:

```
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Check In"
                                      Clicked="CheckInFile"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Check Out"
                                      Clicked="CheckOutFile"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Download"
                                      Clicked="DownloadFile"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Upload Local Copy"
                                      Clicked="UploadFile"/>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DriveItem.Name}"
                                   FontSize="Small" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1""
                                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                                       Text="{Binding PublicationStatus}"
                                     />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and the related cs code:

```
   protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {

        var directoryContents = await App.GraphClient.Sites[siteID].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId]
            .Items
            .Request()
            //.Expand(item => item.DriveItem)
            .Expand("driveItem($select=publication,name,id,description,file,webUrl)")
            .GetAsync();

        SharedDocumentList.ItemsSource = directoryContents.CurrentPage.ToList();
      }
```

For each item that is returned, it contains info about the file - if it's presently checked out or not.  the field is "Level" as you can see below/

```
directoryContents.CurrentPage[i].DriveItem.Publication
{Microsoft.Graph.PublicationFacet}
    AdditionalData: null
    Level: "checkout"
    ODataType: null
    VersionId: "4.0"
```

If the value of Level is "checkout" I want to show the locked icon using this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font
but if it's "published" I'd like to use the unlock icon for example.

Is there a simple way to do some sort of IF statement within the XAML to evaluate the value of DriveItem.Publication.Level and then display the appropriate icon? I started to go down the route of exposing a new property in my codebehind called publicationStatus but ... maybe that's overkill.  I feel like there's a simpler way I'm not thinking of?

**EDIT 1**

So I've updated the xaml to use the datatrigger method but I'm getting the error that the property "RelativeSource" was not found in type BindingExtension.

```
            <ListView x:Name="SharedDocumentList"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"
                 >
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="PublicationStatus" TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                 Value="checkout">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="\uE701"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                Value="published">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="\uE702"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Check In"
                                      Clicked="CheckInFile"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Check Out"
                                      Clicked="CheckOutFile"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Download"
                                      Clicked="DownloadFile"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Upload Local Copy"
                                      Clicked="UploadFile"/>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DriveItem.Name}"
                                   FontSize="Small" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PublicationStatus}"
                                   Tag="{Binding PublicationStatus}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

EDIT 2

This is my attempt at using the ValueConverter.

Here's what the code behind for the class looks like in part:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SPDocumentLibraryContentsPage : ContentPage
{
    public string IconValue { get; set; }
    public SPDocumentLibraryContentsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IconValue = "checkout";
        //this.DataContext doesn't exist.
    }
```

The ListView on the Xaml page looks like this:

<ListView.ItemTemplate>


<ViewCell.ContextActions>




</ViewCell.ContextActions>

```
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DriveItem.Name}"
                                   FontSize="Small" />
```

```
                                <Label x:Name="testBlock" Grid.Column="2"                                      
                                  Text="{Binding IconValue,Converter={StaticResource IconValueConverter}}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And I was able to create the IconConverter class no problems.
Here's just a snippet:

```
 namespace GraphTutorial.Models
 {
     public class IconValueConverter : Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter
     {
     }
```

**EDIT 3**

To get the answer to work I did the following:

```
 <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DriveItem.Name}" FontSize="Small" />
 <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DriveItem.Publication.Level,Converter={StaticResource IconValueConverter}}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that your app is a Xamarin UWP app, not a native UWP app.

You could also try to use a [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-22000) when using binding. What you need to do is create a ValueConverter class and make your own logic for converting different strings to different icons in the ValueConverter.
After that, you just need to use the ValueConverter as a parameter in the binding.

Here is a sample code that I've tested in a native UWP app. And it should work in the Xamarin UWP app. You need to replace `Textblock` with `Label`.

Code-behind:

```
 public class IconValueConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string OutputValue ;

        string textvalue = value as string;
        if (textvalue.Equals("checkout"))
        {
            OutputValue = "\uE701";
        }
        else if (textvalue.Equals("published"))
        {
            OutputValue = "\uE702";
        }
        else 
        {
            OutputValue = "\uE703";
        }


        return OutputValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MainPage:

```
 public string IconValue { get; set;}

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        IconValue = "checkout";

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Xaml code:

```
  <Page.Resources>
    <local:IconValueConverter x:Key="IconValueConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlcok" Text="{Binding IconValue,Converter={StaticResource IconValueConverter}}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Li, I've tried to implement.... the only thing that doesn't work is the "this.DataContext=this;" line.  I don't have that property/ field available.  Please see Edit 2... which I'll add shortly.  But there are no errors when I build ...but nothing shows up either on the gui.  :)

Comment: and yeah, it's a Xamarin Forms UWP app

Comment: @dot OK, it's a Xamarin UWP app. So in Xamarin it should be `this.BindingContext=this`.I'll update my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

There's a smart way to achieve this through a `Trigger` and a `Tag` property to avoid using `IValueConverter` or gaining access to parent `DataContext` from inside a `Style`.

Inside a list view or a root element

```xml
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PublicationStatus" TargetType="Label">        
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Tag"
                     Value="checkout">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="\uE701"/>
            </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="Tag"
                    Value="published">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="\uE702"/>
           </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then in code:

```xml
<Label Grid.Column="1"
       Style="{StaticResource PublicationStatus}"
       Tag="{Binding PublicationStatus}" />
```

You may also reuse a style and put it into some `ResourceDictionary`.

Warning. Not tested.

Comment: So ... the error I'm getting back is that "RelativeSource" is not found in type "BindingExtension"

Comment: Check out my Edit 1

Comment: @dot I apologize with that. Please see an updated answer

Comment: no worries.  I tried your updated solution and it bombs too.  Error is that i'm "missing mandatory property "TargetType" on "Xamarin.Forms.Trigger".  So I added that property on both <Trigger> elements but then it complains that Tag is not legit for Labels.